# Is there a way to reference a class's properties by index rather than by name?

Tags: c#, class, arduino

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class Config {
   public byte ALS { get; set; }
   public bool BCP { get; set; }
   public short NRG { get; set; }
   // 46 more bytes, shorts, and bools
   public byte GRT { get; set; }
}
Config myConfig = new Config();
```

Now let's say I have an Arduino that has that same class defined and it is sending me each prop value as a string one at a time in the same order over serial (with /n chars so I can use SerialPort.ReadLine()). As each value arrives, I want to put it in the next property. I would really like to do something like this:

```
<psudo code>
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    myConfig[i] = (Config[i].GetType())port.ReadLine();  //reference the property by index, not by name
}
</psudo code>
```

Notice I am placing each new arriving value in the next property of my instance after casting the newly arrived value to fit the destination property type. I specify the next property not by name (ALS, BCP. NRG, etc) but by index (0, 1, 2, 3, etc).

Is there a way to do this?

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something as below...

```
public class Config {
   [Display(Order=0)]
   public byte ALS { get; set; }

   [Display(Order=1)]
   public bool BCP { get; set; }

   [Display(Order=2)]
   public short NRG { get; set; }

   [Display(Order=3)]
   public byte GRT { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute `Display` is from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace

And now you can write an extension method as below

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty(this Type type, int index)
{
      return type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => ((DisplayAttribute)p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)[0]).Order == index);
}
```

Now you can use this and assign the values to the fields on your object as shown below

```
Config config = new Config();
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
     config.GetType().GetProperty(i).SetValue(config, port.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Gorgeous! (Even more so, because after reading it slowly, I actually understood it!)  One correction tho, I can't actually put the ReadLine() in SetValue... ReadLine is producing strings which don't cast worth squat into byte types, so I had to do a bit of pre-pocessing of the ReadLine val before using it in SetValue.

Comment: Glad to hear!! Yah, my bad!! I should have added a note. This code I meant is just trying to show you the way to do!!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several solutions, each with his pros and cons (in no particular order)

1. Use several arrays to store your variables and an array of types to know where to put the nth result you get.
2. Use reflection to get all relevant properties and modify them. BUT - get them once and store them, don't get them each time. And don't depend on the order (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) - create your own attribute of order and mark your properties. So when you'll have an order of your choice which will not change when you rename or remove a property (or when MS will change .net).
3. Use an array of Objects to store your data, but parse each from string using the correct type. You can then have your properties wrap the array.

   public byte ALS
   {
       get
       {
           return (byte)m_properties[ALS_INDEX];
       }
       set
       {
           m_properties[ALS_INDEX] = value;
       }
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to iterate over properties, this will not give you an indexed access but I think the properties are returned in a deterministic order.

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(flags);

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + property.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```